# Bash wrapper for R

Tags: r, bash

I'd like to call some R function by giving it some arguments from Bash and store the value that this function returns. Something like

```
#!/usr/bin/Rscript

myfunction(arg1, arg2){
...
...
return(ValueToReturn)
}
```

and call it from Bash

```
$ returnedvalue = on ./myscript.r call myfunction -arg1 -arg2
```

So far the only solution I could think of is to write the arguments on a file and then call the R script ('./myscrpt.r') where 'myfunction()' reads the arguments from the file, and then write 'ValueToReturn' on a file that I can read from Bash.

Comment: Not directly answering, but this help page  may be of interest:   https://vscentrum.be/neutral/documentation/cluster-doc/software/R-CLA-in-scripts

Comment: I'm not 100% clear on what you are looking for but I feel like the package [littler](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/littler.html) might be useful to you; I can't test this at the moment because I'd have to reboot into my Linux partition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible to my knowledge owing to the way parent and child shells are related: child shells are not allowed to alter their parent's environment which is why putting:

```
system(paste0("export returnedvalue=", ValuetoReturn))
```

Will only export that variable to the current environment and any subsequent child shells the environment spawns.

An ugly way could be to save the output to a file with:

```
system(paste0("echo 'export returnedvalue=", ValuetoReturn, "' > setvars.txt"))
```

Then in the parent shell source the file:

```
. ./setvars.txt
```

At least this way you can save more than one output.

Comment: It's not all *that* bad to store results to a file and then add a couple bash commands to load the file's contents into a variable.